# Using Magento with a simple one-product site

Tags: magento, e-commerce, shopping-cart

What's the best way to integrate Magento with a simple HTML-based single product site?

I envision installing Magento, and then the existing site just "hooks" into Magento versus using the entire Magento framwork, etc.  I don't want to use Magento as a "CMS" I just want to use it to handle the order processing.

Any tips or suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: What are you using on the existing site? Does it have to be magento? Wordpress for example has a number of plugins to do simple shopping carts.

Comment: Currently using osCommerce.  I like all the extra features that Magento has out-of-the-box.  I plan to offer extra options during checkout (support plans, physical shipment, etc) and thought it would be nice to have Magento handle all the payment processing.

Comment: Magento seems like overkill if you've only one product to sell. It really is monolithic. It was also very slow the last time I tried to use it.

Comment: It is only slow if misconfigured or running on a low-end server.

Answer (score 1):

Using Magento seems bit overkill but you could create separate landing page and use link to add product to cart. On default settings this redirects customer to Magento shopping cart where they begin checkout process.

Use product **Id**, not **SKU**:
http://www.magento.com/checkout/cart/add/product/123/